# Laravel uploading file using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, laravel

I'm using the Laravel framework. I have a form of adding a new item to the database and in that form the user can also drag and drop a file. Then, a progress bar is displayed until it's completed, using Ajax for uploading the file to the server.

Once submitting that form, I run the `addItem` function in a controller and I want to do/check:

1. That the file is already hosted in the server (successful upload)
2. If the file is hosted in the server, how do I find it? (I gave it a random name)
3. If the user chose not to submit the form, I wish to erase that file from the server, so I won't have files that are not connected to any item on my database

Can you suggest any ideas on how to complete these tasks?

Comment: See [my answer updated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25442012/2389232) and the jsfiddle! Now you can show the progress of the upload!

Answer (score 7):

To send files by AJAX you need to use [`FormData`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20100907/) which is a class of [`XMLHttpRequest2`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20100907/), it doesn't work with IE<10.

You also need [AJAX2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20100907/) to show progress.

**SAMPLE SUBMIT FORM WITH FILES AND PROGRESS VIA AJAX**:

Here I have made an example. In this example the form sends the data and files via AJAX using `FormData` and show the upload progress percentage in `#progress` using the `progress` event. Obviously it is a sample and it could be changed to adapt it.

```
$('form').submit(function(e) { // capture submit
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData(this); // XXX: Neex AJAX2

    // You could show a loading image for example...

    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      xhr: function() { // custom xhr (is the best)

           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           var total = 0;

           // Get the total size of files
           $.each(document.getElementById('files').files, function(i, file) {
                  total += file.size;
           });

           // Called when upload progress changes. xhr2
           xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                  // show progress like example
                  var loaded = (evt.loaded / total).toFixed(2)*100; // percent

                  $('#progress').text('Uploading... ' + loaded + '%' );
           }, false);

           return xhr;
      },
      type: 'post',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: fd,
      success: function(data) {
           // do something...
           alert('uploaded');
      }
    });
});
```

See how works!!: http://jsfiddle.net/0xnqy7du/3/

**LARAVEL**:

In `laravel` you can get the file with [`Input::file`](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files), move to another location and save in the database if you need it:

```
Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

// Sample save in the database
$image = new Image();
$image->path = $destinationPath . $fileName;
$image->name = 'Webpage logo';
$image->save();
```

Comment: I think he wants more than only the ajax function. Moreover, IE8 is still much used (btw the default browser in my company).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but thats not what i ment. I have an ajax function that upload a file, once i submit the form, i want to check if the file finished to upload and get the path to it, because I gave it a random name.

Comment: I have updaded my answer to include a progress. I am making a example in jsfiddle. XHR2 is not compatible with IE8 and there isn't other solution.

Comment: Just to point the fact if the user doesn't have the good browser or if javascript is disabled.

Comment: See [my answer updated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25442012/2389232) and the jsfiddle! Now you can show the progress of the upload!