# Unable to view image data upon posting a form

Tags: php, image, laravel-5, ajax-upload

Problem: unable to see file image upload data. **Getting null returned**

Im trying to post an ad and i would like to see the data that i'm posting

So my form looks like so:

```
{!! Form::open(['data-remote', 'class' => 'form-vertical', 'route' => 'dashboard.ad.create', 'files' => true, 'id' => 'createAd']) !!}

            <div class="cover_photo">
                {!! Form::label('cover_photo', 'Cover Photo') !!}

                {!! Form::file('cover_photo') !!}
            </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the field with the issue, the file form field named **cover_photo**

My form request class has the following in the rules array

```
'cover_photo' => 'image',
```

I'm using ajax to post the form. All im doing in my controller is

```
public function postStoreAd(PostAnAddRequest $request) {
    dd($request->all());
}
```

The weird thing is i get all the other form fields data. Except for **cover_photo**
In fact when i try to do the following i get **null**:

```
dd($request->file('cover_photo')); // return null
```

I've ensured that i'm using the

```
'files' => true, // In my Form::open()
```

Please help and thank you :)

Comment: have you tried submitting the form without ajax? hope you know ajax request doesn't support file upload except ofcourse if you use iframe or some other methods?

Comment: I'm now getting the data without ajax. Im not sure how to implement an ajax file upload. Thank you for helping

Comment: Yeah. there are many jquery plugins out there you could use. check out these, https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-ajax-file-upload, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441893/laravel-uploading-file-using-ajax

Comment: show your ajax code..

Comment: you can also check out this jquery plugin http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 0):

So in my jquery i have used **data.serialize()** which i found out won't work thanks to this [article](http://portfolio.planetjon.ca/2014/01/26/submit-file-input-via-ajax-jquery-easy-way/)

Using this implementation Form, i was able to obtain the data i needed

```
var form = $(this);

var formdata = new FormData(form[0]); //form.serialize() wont work

form.find('div.alert').remove();

e.preventDefault();

var action = $(this).attr('action');

var method = $('input[name=_method]').val() || 'POST';

$.ajax({
    type: method,
    action: action,
    data: formdata, //form.serialize() wont work
    processData: false, // You need this
    contentType: false, // You need this
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        var errors = data.responseJSON;

        $.each(errors, function(key, value) {
            console.log(key + ' - ' + value);
            $('#' + key).after('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + value + '</div>');
        });

    }

});
```